# Is it possible to get subject distance from an EXIF data of a jpeg image?

Tags: exif

how to get the distance between subject and camera from an EXIF data?

Comment: If you knew the focal length of the lens and the average size of someone's head you might get a rough idea. The bigger problem is that digital camera sensors are usually not full frame, so there is a multiplication factor for the lens's focal length (e.g. Canon's older line of cameras has a 1.6x factor due to the small sensor).

Answer (score 1):

The formula to calculate working distance from a subject filling a frame vertically is (all measurements are in millimeters (mm):

Working Distance = (Sensor Height + Subject Height) * Focal Length / Sensor Height

Don't worry about crop factor for an APS-C sensor here. Canon APS-C sensors are 16mm in height. Plug in 16 into the formula for Sensor Height. For reference, sensor width can be substituted too in the formula for sensor height (useful for vertically-oriented shots).

The result of the calculation will leave you with a solution in mm. Divide that number by 1000 to get meters. Then, multiply by 3.28 if you want the distance in feet.